# Reading json string from textfield in php when form submitted

Tags: php, json, forms, codeigniter-3

I am trying to read json string from input hidden field on form submit :

```
<form action="<?=base_url()?>update-basic" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">    
<input type="hidden" name="old_image" value="<?=json_encode($package_detail->slider_image)?>">
<button type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Update</button>
</form>
```

The json string comes from database here. I want to get the json string in server side when the form is submitted

**PHP**

```
$json=file_get_contents('php://input');
var_dump($json);
```

but I get empty string as the value of `$json`

However the json string is correctly printed in html

```
<input type="hidden" name="old_image" value=""{\"0\":\"FB_IMG_1.jpg\"}"">
```

I am using codeigniter.

Comment: try, var_dump($_POST('old_image'));

Comment: give name attribute to your button element

Comment: Its also give null string

Comment: where are you posting form to ? form action url?

Comment: Yes i am posting to url

Comment: what is that url?

Comment: Check the baseurl in my form

Comment: show full code where you receiving form values.

Comment: @jothi my json string is in correct format

Comment: did you tried my comment .because the value attribute wrapped in single quotes because inside json string should be wrapped in double quotes so try that @BlessanKurien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
<input type="text" name="old_image" value='{"0":"FB_IMG_1.jpg"}' />

<?php

  $ss = '{"0":"FB_IMG_1.jpg"}';

 echo "<PRE>";
 print_r(json_decode($ss,true));
 echo "</PRE>";

?>
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => FB_IMG_1.jpg
)
```

Comment: Its worked but when i try json_decode i  will string instead of array

Comment: i think your missing something. i tried in my localhost its works fine @BlessanKurien

Comment: Got it its typo:)